# How to get the access token in a service in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I have an application and I want to use a hybrid flow to call an API from my MVC web application. The API is secured and requires an access token (JWT). The code part on the API side is done.
But how can I send my access token from my MVC application to the API in a service? I want to use a "generic" service for this that uses an httpclient.

I know that in controllers you can use

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

or

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();
```

But how can I access the access token in a service? 
Tried this too, but didn't work

```
    var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
```

Side question: how can I set the access token for the httpclient in the constructor of my service? (Using async methods is not possible) so I can't use this:

```
protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; private set; }

public MyGenericHttpClientService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)

{
            var accessToken = await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            HttpClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
}
```

Comment: Why didn’t IHttpContextAccessor work?

Comment: Can't use that one in a constructor, cause it's async.

Comment: I can do it before every method, but wanted to know if there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: how did you resolve the HttpClient? If you are using IHttpClientFactory, you can configure a DelegatingHandler in Startup that gets the token from IHttpContextAccessor and set it to outgoing requests.

Comment: That sounds like the thing i'm looking for! Do you have an example?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `IHttpClientFactory`, you can configure your `HttpClient` as follows by adding a `DelegatingHandler` in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<TokenHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient().AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenHandler>();
```

And `TokenHandler` can be as follows:

```
public class TokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TokenHandler(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

For more information on `IHttpClientFactory`, you can see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).